# How to set date field in HTML form and how can i retrieve the date in servlets?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I need to set a date field in my html form. After submitting the form the request goes to the servlet and tha data will be stored in database. In servlets how can i retrieve the date field?
            Please help me.

-renu

Answer (score 2):

You'll get it out of the HttpRequest parameters:

```
DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dateAsString = httpRequest.getParameter("form-name-for-the-date-here");
Date dateAsObject = dateFormatter.parse(dateAsString);
```

If you're using Spring you should use their data binding API.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is good. If you want to change your format at database level use this format.

In `PreparedStatement`:

- For MySQL TIMESTAMP use `to_timestamp( ? ,'dd-mm-yyyy %h:%i:%s')` format.
- For Oracle TIMESTAMP use `to_date(dateAsString ,'DD-MM-RR HH24:MI:SS')` format.
- For MySQL DATE use `to_timestamp( ? ,'dd-mm-yyyy')` format.
- For Oracle DATE use `to_date(? ,'DD-MM-RR')` format.

Set `dateAsString` in `PreparedStatement`.

```
String dateAsString = httpRequest.getParameter("form-name-for-the-date-here");
```

Comment: I wouldn't massage date forth and back as string. This is a performance pain whenever you want to select rows by date. E.g. between certain timestamps, or months or days, etc. Use the right type for the value!

Comment: @paragjioshi, why don't you simply use `PreparedStatement.setDate()` method? The vendors who implements the database driver will have optimised ways to store dates in their respective database servers. All this conversion is unecessary.